# ghc - square brackets on command line?

Tags: haskell, ghc

On this page:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Parsing

it shows ghc being called thusly:

```
ghc -package parsec -o simple_parser [../code/listing3.4.hs listing3.4.hs]
```

What are the square brackets for? I get an error with I use it with ghc 7.0.4. Is this some sort of way to specify a search path for input files?

Comment: Did you try quoting this (with single quotes)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GHC doesn't accept any such command-line syntax; to compile `listing3.4.hs`, you should use:

```
ghc -o simple_parser listing3.4.hs
```

(You don't have to specify packages these days; GHC will automatically link them in as required.)

This is a wiki markup mistake, caused by an automatic conversion of the original *Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours* to wiki format. On [this page](http://jonathan.tang.name/files/scheme_in_48/tutorial/parser.html#symbols), you can see that in the corresponding code block, `listing3.1.hs` is linked to [a copy of the file](http://jonathan.tang.name/files/scheme_in_48/code/listing3.1.hs). This relative link was converted to the MediaWiki external link syntax, which, of course, does not work inside code blocks. (Even if it did, a relative path is used, so it wouldn't link anywhere useful.)